# Android Studio - getApplicationContext logcat error

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When you press the button on the main screen, it goes to the animal hospital list screen
I was compiling a list of veterinary hospitals with Recyclerview.
(I have created intents on the main screen, but I have not yet created intents on the animal hospital list screen.)

All other codes have not failed, but the getApplicationContext() part will fail.

logcat: 'hospitalListAdapter(android.content.Context, java.util.ArrayList<com.example.project.hospitalListItem>)' in 'com.example.project.hospitalListAdapter' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Context)'

```
hospitalActivity.java (List of Animal Hospitals)

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class hospitalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    RecyclerView hospital_list;
    hospitalListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hospital);

        hospital_list = findViewById(R.id.hospital_list);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        hospital_list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new hospitalListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        hospital_list.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
        adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
        adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
        adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
        adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
        adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
        adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
        adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
        adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
        adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
        adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
        adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));

    }
}

hospitalListItem.java (ListItem)

public class hospitalListItem {
    int resId;
    String title;
    String address;
    String phone;
    String guri;

    public hospitalListItem(int resId, String title, String address, String phone, String guri) {
        this.resId = resId;
        this.title = title;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.guri = guri;
    }
}


hospitalListAdapter.java (ListAdapter)

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class hospitalListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<hospitalListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<hospitalListItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public hospitalListAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<hospitalListItem> items) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public hospitalListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hospital_design, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull hospitalListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        hospitalListItem item = items.get(position);
        holder.setItem(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void addItem(hospitalListItem item){
        items.add(item);
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView listEdit_tv;
        TextView title_tv;
        TextView addr_tv;
        TextView phone_tv;
        TextView guri_tv;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            listEdit_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listEdit_tv);
            title_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_tv);
            addr_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addr_tv);
            phone_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_tv);
            guri_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.guri_tv);
        }
        public void setItem(hospitalListItem item){
            listEdit_tv.setImageResource(item.resId);
            title_tv.setText(item.title);
            addr_tv.setText(item.address);
            phone_tv.setText(item.phone);
            guri_tv.setText(item.guri);
        }
    }
}
```

I need your help. I'd appreciate your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzd2b.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIluh.png)

Comment: The constructor of `hospitalListAdapter` expects one more argument `items` - you're simply not passing it. There is no problem with `getApplicationContext`.

Comment: public hospitalListAdapter(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
} Should I write it like this?

Comment: @kimzero Yes you can remove this list from constructor as well, but then you will have to pass each item one by one to the adapter and adapter will have to update each time you pass the new item. Instead pass all items at once, as answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public hospitalListAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<hospitalListItem> items)
```

This is the constructor of your hospitalListAdapter Class. Whenever, you want to create objects of a class you need to call its constructor and pass the parameters. Here the constructor requires a Context and a ArrayList<>, so you need to pass both but you are only passing the context.

```
// also pass the list to the constructor here
adapter = new hospitalListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```

Correct way:

```
// here I am creating an empty list and passing it to adapter as required.
ArrayList<hospitalListItem> list = new ArrayList<hospitalListItem>();
adapter = new hospitalListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
```

Also, Instead of passing items one by one to your adapter you can first add them to your list and then pass the whole list itself, as shown above.

```
// passing items one by one to the list
adapter.addItem(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
```

Do this instead.

```
// create a list
ArrayList<hospitalListItem> list = new ArrayList<hospitalListItem>();

// add items to the list
list.add(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));
list.add(new hospitalListItem(R.drawable.nuribom, "동물병원", "종로구","02-33", "어쩌구저쩌구"));

// add remaining items here

// Finally, pass the whole list to adapter at once.
adapter = new hospitalListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
```

Comment: Thank you always. Thanks to you, I solved it well. Have a happy day!